# Feminine singular pronoun “la” with no explicit antecedent

Tags: pronombres

This passage is from *El coronel no tiene quien le escriba* by Gabriel García Márquez.

> Durante la lectura pensó en su pensión de veterano. Diecinueve años antes, cuando el congreso promulgó la ley, se inició un proceso de justificación que duró ocho años. Luego necesitó seis años más para hacerse incluir en el escalafón. Ésa fue la última carta que recibió el coronel.
>   Terminó después del toque de queda. Cuando iba a apagar la lámpara cayó en la cuenta de que su mujer estaba despierta.
>   —¿Tienes todavía aquel recorte?
>   La mujer pensó.
>   —Sí. Debe estar con los otros papeles.
>   Salió del mosquitero y extrajo del armario un cofre de madera con un paquete de cartas ordenadas por las fechas y aseguradas con una cinta elástica. Localizó un anuncio de una agencia de abogados que se comprometía a una gestión activa de las pensiones de guerra.
>   —Desde que estoy con el tema de que cambies de abogado ya hubiéramos tenido tiempo hasta de gastarnos la plata —dijo la mujer, entregando a su marido el recorte del periódico—. Nada sacamos con que nos **la** metan en el cajón como a los indios.

I’m wondering how the pronoun *la* in the last sentence should be interpreted. Is it part of a fixed phrase and doesn’t refer to anything in particular, or would you assume the speaker has something concrete in mind that she would refer to with a feminine singular noun, such as *pensión* and *justificación*, although neither she nor her interlocutor used any of those words earlier? I don't think it refers to *plata* because the money comes only after the papers are processed and what is put on the back burner is the papers.

The English version doesn’t translate *la* and treats *nos* as if it is a direct object of *meter*.

> We’re not getting anything out of their putting us away on a shelf as they do with the Indians.

Would the Spanish sentence sound as natural if *la* was omitted?

Comment: Frankly, i think it refers to the money: la plata. meter la plata en un cajon and the fact it is not translated doesn't mean much. The order of words: Nos la metan is if they stick it on a shelf **for us**. But be aware that translation does not require the translation of every word. cajon is shelf or coffin. This may be stick it in a coffin for us. Not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is this:
Nada sacamos *con que* nos la metan en el cajón como a los indios.
The *la* refers to *la plata.*

The use of *con que* here means: if they [do something]; it is idiomatic.

It would be the same meaning as: Nada sacamos si la metiese [la plata] en el cajon.

*We get nothing out of it if they stick it [our money] in the coffin like with the Indians*.

The English translation had a mistake. ***cajon*** here is **a coffin.** Indians (Amerindians) buried their worldly valuables alongside the deceased for their trip to the afterlife. Similar to the Egyptians. That is the reference or allusion here.

"nos la metan" is another idiomatic use. It means: if they "enclose" or "stick" our money in the coffin. And to make it regular speech, "stick" works best  here.

> meter here is the first entry in the Real Academia dictionary:
>
> 1. tr. Encerrar, introducir o incluir algo dentro de otra cosa o en alguna parte. U. t. c. prnl.
>    Translation of the entry
> 2. To enclose, to put in or include something inside something else or somewhere. In every day language, also *to stick something in something*. **Also used as a reflexive verb**. [Real Academia_meter](https://dle.rae.es/meter)

Meterse is used a lot in Spanish in various contexts, as in:

- Nos metierón un gol. (Nos lo metieron) They made a goal against us. But in Spanish, it's forceful.
- Le metí un puñetazo. (Selo metí) I gave him a (big) punch.
- Le metí el dinero en el bolsillo. (Selo metí) en el bolsillo. I put or stuck the money in his pocket.

However, in the sentence, to make it ring true, the English can put the *nos* of the reflexive in the possessive pronoun by saying our money OR just leaving it out.

Comment: If the reference is to the Indians burying their valuables, what does the preposition ***a*** do in *a los indios*? Wouldn't they be the agents of the action, not the objects?

Comment: @aguijonazo It's an ellipsis or truncation of: "como meten a los indios en cajones". meter a alguien en un lugar". meter takes the preposition **a**. **Meter a los perros** en sus jardines.

Comment: So the Indians are the objects of burying? It doesn’t seem to make much sense to me to say they bury the money on us like they bury the Indians. I would think it makes more sense to say they bury the money on us like the Indians bury their money (or valuables) if the sentence alludes to what you say it does.

Comment: @aguijonazo There is no bury money **on us**. It's stick or put the money in the coffin like the Indians stick it in their coffins. meter takes **a**.  **Nada sacamos con que nos la metan en el cajón como [la meten] a los indios [en el cajon]**. I think I have helped as much as I can here. And yes, cajon is coffin. And that is the ellipsis.

Comment: @aguijonazo You are mixing up the Spanish and English. I just gave you a sentence above that works for what is elided. The entire phrase has a elliptical structure: **como [la meten] a los indios [en el cajon]**.  Meter takes a. It is an **indirect object**.

Comment: My confusion was more in how to connect the sentence with the alluded practice than in how to parse the sentence itself. I can understand *los indios* is an indirect object. I was somehow under the impression that “coffin” was used in a figurative sense in reference to keeping the documents in the drawer without processing them. It makes more sense now that I understand the word in a literal sense. So she is basically saying “It’s no use if they put the money in *our* coffins after we die,” and that is likened to the Indians putting valuables in the coffins when people die. Is that correct?

Comment: I thought your example with *los perros* was a bit misleading, though.

Comment: Yes, and I believe I have now said it three times. You can **meter a [anyone or anything]** en un lugar. The reason for the confusion in my opinion is because the other answers didn't see that la referred to la plata.

Comment: The problem was in an attempt to connect the sentence with the alluded practice, I was putting “los indios” in the subject’s position, like they put the money in the (figurative) coffin like the Indians put valuables in their (literal) coffins. If it’s an indirect object just like *nos*, it being preceded by *a* makes complete sense. I just thought *los perros* was a direct object. Anyway, thanks for your help. It’s clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Como se ha indicado se esta hablando de la pensión del Coronel. La solicitud y gestión de la pensión lleva demasiados años y el gobierno aún no ha comenzado a pagarlo. Por tanto, se esta buscando un nuevo abogado más diligente que pueda acelerar el papeleo.

"*Nada sacamos con que nos la metan en el cajón como a los indios*", esta indicando que no se gana nada si nuestro expediente se mete en un cajón, es decir, se refiere a una solicitud o petición. Por tanto, cuando dice, ..." *con que nos* **la** *metan en el cajón como a los indios*", se refiere al expediente o petición y la esta comparando con aquellas otras peticiones que hacen los indios al gobierno y que éste deja en un cajón olvidadas, así pues, igualmente el gobierno puede dejar olvidada en un cajón su petición de pensión.

---

*¿La oración en español sonaría tan natural si se omitiera* **la** *?*

Nada sacamos con que nos metan en el cajón como a los indios.

"...nos metan en un cajón como a los indios", la verdad es que suena bastante extraño.

- No, no sonaría natural, faltarían elementos. En mi opinión, si lo traduces al inglés debes indicar cual es el objeto al que se refiere "la", pues de lo contrarío el lector se confundiría ya que no aparecería claro.
- "Nada sacamos con que nos la metan en el cajón como a los indios".

La versión larga;

- "**Nada sacamos si el expediente de petición de la pensión se mete en un cajón, como hacen con las peticiones de los indios**"

---

*La versión en inglés no traduce "la" y trata a "nos" como si fuera un objeto directo de meter*

"No sacamos nada con que nos metan en un estante como hacen con los indios".

No es una buena traducción, el traductor no se ha percatado que se están hablando o refiriéndose a una "petición", en este caso, a *la petición de solicitud de una pensión*, y por tanto lo omite, confundiendo con ello al lector que no sabe muy bien que es lo que hacen con los indios o con sus cosas. Espero te haya servido.

Comment: ¿Sonaría igualmente natural is *la* se reemplazara por *lo* ya que *expediente* es masculino?

Comment: "Nada sacamos con que nos lo metan en el cajón como a los indios". No, no suena natural ya que sigue sin entenderse correctamente la parte que le sigue,  "como a los indios". Lo natural es que el escritor lo hubiera aclarado de forma más precisa. ("Nada sacamos con que nuestra petición la metan en un cajón como las peticiones que hacen los indios") o ("Nada sacamos con que el expediente nos lo metan en el cajón como hacen con los expedientes de los indios"), al utilizar el autor "la", se entiende que es "la petición" o "las peticiones", mejor que "el expediente" o" los expedientes".

Comment: El hecho de utilizar o escribir "el expediente" o "los expedientes", era una forma de que tú lo comprendieras mejor. Sin embargo, es igualmente correcto referirse a ellas como "la petición de la pensión" y "las peticiones de los indios".

Comment: Creo que se trata de la plata. No se refiere al expediente. La palabra plata es feminina y bien cercana.

Comment: No creo que la "plata", el dinero, sea posible que aguarde en un cajón. Por otra lado, la pensión de guerra es igualmente dinero. Lo importante no es eso. El problema es que el autor da por hecho que el lector conoce lo que hacen con el conjunto de cosas que solicitan los indios  "como a los indios" y es que éstas quedan olvidadas en un cajón, de ahí la confusión, ya que el escritor no es completamente claro en esta afirmación y hay que sobrentenderlo de la lectura.

Comment: Da igual la "plata" o "la pensión", ambas son dinero, lo importante, como digo, es entender que puede suceder con aquello que sea, dinero, pensiones, peticiones..., lo mismo que les ocurre a los indios cuando solicitan algo, es decir, que las cosas queden olvidadas en un cajón. "Nada sacamos si la petición de la pensión (la plata, el dinero) se mete en un cajón, como hacen con los expedientes de los indios"

Comment: Claro que si. Los indios se entierran con sus objetos de valor.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the war pension:

> Localizó un anuncio de una agencia de abogados que se comprometía a una gestión activa de **las pensiones de guerra**

The bureaucracy takes too long to fulfill the colonel's wish to receive the pension. Then his wife reproaches him for the possible inefficiency of the new lawyers:

> We’re not getting anything out of their putting **us** away on a shelf as they do with the Indians.

Where "US" is our "war pension" procedure.

In Spanish:

> Nada sacamos con que nos **la** metan en el cajón como a los indios.

Or:

> Nada sacamos con que `a la pensión de guerra` nos la metan en el cajón como a los indios

Where we all know in bureaucracy it's a very common procedure to put files in a drawer and forget about them.